# OpenACC and Unified memory

Tags: cuda, openmp, openacc

Hello I try to run my program(which use OpenACC,OpenMP and CUDA Unified memory) in Google Cloud with Tesla V100 and it is run succesfully, but I use 1xGPU 8xCores and 50GB of RAM and try to use all RAM what I have, so I control RAM consumption using htop and all work perfect when I use small amount of RAM I have this data:
VIRT = 26.8G, RES = 21.5G, SHR = 7440M. 
And when I try to use more RAM, htop displayed this:
VIRT = 27.2G, RES = 22.3G, SHR = 7700M - it is like "limit".
Program allocate data and "stuck" at this parameters(allocating with speed like 5MB\s). What I can do with this? And how can I use more GPUs with CUDA unified memory? I also trying use 2xV100, but have no difference(I was thinking that I will be able to use 2xVRAM).

Answer (score 1):

I believe UVM will work out of the box (minus some initial startup costs) with multiple GPUs. As mentioned [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-multi-gpu), managed allocations can migrate to other processors on demand, so accessing data on another GPU should just trigger a migration, invisible to the programmer. I'm a bit confused on the rest of the question though.